# how to create Antlr3 lexer token for word inside string

Tags: java, antlr3, lexer

I want to write a lexer rule for matching certain text inside string. Following inputs must be tokenized as the lexer token.

- ' abcd  Text abcd'
- 'Text'
- '1234 Text abcd'
- " abcd  Text abcd"
- "Text"

Note: Text is common in all.

---

I want a lexer token for all strings which have 'Text' word in it.

TEXT_STR : ('\'' | '\"') 'Text' ('\'' | '\"');

e.g: Above token is created when Text is exactly between single quote or double quote (e.g.: 'Text'). But this token would not be created for stings like this:

' abcd  Text abcd'

I want same token to be created for all such cases. What I need actually is:

Single or Double Quote followed by any characters followed by 'Text' followed by any characters then followed by single or Double Quote(matching to start quote).

Answer (score 1):

```
TEXT_STR
    :   SINGLE_QUOTE (~SINGLE_QUOTE)* 'Text' (~SINGLE_QUOTE)* SINGLE_QUOTE
    |   DOUBLE_QUOTE (~DOUBLE_QUOTE)* 'Text' (~DOUBLE_QUOTE)* DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

fragment SINGLE_QUOTE : '\'';
fragment DOUBLE_QUOTE : '"';
```

Comment: 'Text' is already a token in my grammar. I am getting error: Decision can match input using multiple alternatives.

Comment: Well, should `'Text'` match your other rule, or `TEXT_STR`?

Comment: If Text is outside quote then it should match with other rule. If its inside Quotes then with TEXT_STR

Comment: I want an action to be taken on encountering certain token in file. Token is a keyword. So I have created a lexer rule for that token. But it is getting executed when lexer sees it inside string. I don't want it to be executed for inside string token.